# Cannot upload file in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading MVC website on web-server for the first time. Everything worked well except file upload option. Whenever I try to upload a file, it prompts me this error:

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path
>   '' is not rooted.

Error details is somehow showing a path of my project that I created on my local machine.

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The SaveAs method is configured
>   to require a rooted path, and the path '' is not rooted.    at
>   Printrpk.Controllers.ProductController.Create(ProductModels product)
>   in
>   C:\Projects\Carting\Carting\Carting\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line
>   145

I have tried multiple ways to check if my code is wrong, but I couldn't able to make it work.

This is what I have written under **Create** Action

```
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
    fName = file.FileName;
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}images", Server.MapPath(@"/")));
        var pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ProductImages");
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
        if (!isExists)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        }

        path = string.Format("{0}//{1}", pathString, filename);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
}
```

This controller works fine when I do not upload any image. I have checked my web.config which is already pointing towards web-server.

This is included in `Create` View

```
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
```

Also I already have targeted folder in my base folder

Comment: have you checked AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory value?

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath()` - e.g. `var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages"), fileName); file.SaveAs(path);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have already tried this. Doesn't work. Weird

Comment: Does you app contain a folder `ProductImages`? And when you use it, what is the value of `path`?

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, I got the issue. Your code does work now. I was inserting wrong variable. Please write your answer below so that I can vote it :)

Comment: Stephen is correct, use relative url or Server.MapPath().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath()` to get the physical path that corresponds to a virtual path. Assuming you app contains a folder named `Images` which contains a subfolder named `ProductImages`, then

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ProductImages"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Side note: Consider adding a parameter `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file` to you POST method so it is bound with the selected files (or better, include that as a property in your view model) rather than using `Request.Files`